# Haskell: find to 2 numbers from list that add up to target sum

Tags: haskell, dynamic

My aim: given a list of numbers, find the indices of the first pair of numbers that add up to a target number. This is part of the problem given in an old google-code-jam challenge. https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p0

```
λ: check 14 [2,4,6,8,10]
(3,4)
```

NB indexed from 1

My solution is to create a map then iterate over the list of numbers; on each iteration, check if complement (ie target - current value) exists in the map. If it does I return the current index and index of complement from map. If it does not exist, recurse with current index inserted into map and rest of item list.

1st attempt:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap as M

check :: Int -> [Int] -> (Int, Int)
check target items = go M.empty (zip [1..] items)
  where
    go m ((i,v):vs) = case M.lookup (target - v) m of
      Just x  -> (x,i)
      Nothing -> go (M.insert v i m) vs
```

1. Is this a correct implementation of my algorithm? It works on my test cases, but I feel that it is not correct Haskell way to write it.
2. Is HashMap the correct data structure to use? or would something like Vector be better?

Also, is this actually a good algorithm for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks okay. The fact that `go` is partial is a bit disturbing, but the problem statement does say that a solution is supposed to exist.

`IntMap` should be preferred when the keys are `Int`. Then `Map` for other keys that are small in size. `HashMap` for larger keys (like `String`).

An immutable `Vector` would not be right because updating it is too expensive. It is possible to solve the problem with a mutable `MVector`, because the values of the input are quite small (`<= 2000`), but that would be more awkward than your current solution in Haskell.

Comment: How would you write go to handle cases with no solution?

Comment: If there may be no solution, then I would change the signature of `check` to output `Maybe (Int, Int)` to reflect that. When `go` finds a solution, `Just (x, i)`; when there is no solution `go _ [] = Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach which does not need map (though still asymptotically equivalent to the OP's version) is to traverse sorted list from both ends moving left or right "pointer" depending on the current sum:

```
import Data.List (sort)

check t xs =
  let sxs = sort xs
  in go sxs (reverse sxs)
  where
    go ls@(l:ls') rs@(r:rs') | l < r = 
      case compare (l + r) t of
        LT -> go ls' rs
        EQ -> Just (l,r)
        GT -> go ls rs'
    go _ _ = Nothing
```

For simplicity assuming that the numbers in list are all distinct.

UPDATE: Missed the fact that we are after indexes, not values.

UPDATE2: And handle non-distinct case:

```
check t xs =
  let sxs = sort $ zip xs [1..]
  in go sxs (reverse sxs)
  where
    go ls@((l,li):ls') rs@((r,ri):rs') | li /= ri = 
      case compare (l + r) t of
        LT -> go ls' rs
        EQ -> Just (li,ri)
        GT -> go ls rs'
    go _ _ = Nothing
```

Or we can just find all of them:

```
checkAll t xs =
  let sxs = sort $ zip xs [1..]
  in go sxs (reverse sxs) []
  where
    go ls@((l,li):ls') rs@((r,ri):rs') ms | li /= ri = 
      case compare (l + r) t of
        LT -> go ls' rs ms
        EQ -> go ls' rs ((li,ri):ms)
        GT -> go ls rs' ms
    go _ _ ms = ms
```

Comment: the numbers in the lists are not all distinct. Does this still work?

Comment: @matthias Now it does, I believe. See UPDATE2